# Stationary distribution of "probabilistic geometric series" with two alternative ratios

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, power-series

I have an iterative process starting at $X_0=2$. In each iteration $i=1,2,\ldots$, the value of $X_i$ is determined based on the value of $X_{i-1}$ as follows: With probability 0.5, $X_i=qX_{i-1}+1$, otherwise, $X_i=(1-q)X_{i-1}+1$, with $0<q<1$.

I am interested in the stationary distribution of this process, i.e. $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}P(X_i=x)$. Specifically, I am interested in an explanation why this distribution seems so "rough" and "repetitive" (at least when numerically solving it, see below). Alternatively, I would be grateful for any reference to the literature on this distribution, the name of the process, or anything else to find out more.

[image: Stationary Distribution]

The image shows the numerically obtained distribution by running the above described algorithm n=100000 times for 10000 iterations, each, with $q=\pi/5$. Dash dotted lines are the two limits $\frac{1}{1-q}$ and $\frac{1}{q}$ corresponding to the solution of the deterministic geometric series with coefficient $q$ and $(1-q)$. The numerically obtained distribution seems not to change significantly when increasing the number of iterations.

## Edit: Preliminary ideas

Based on the reference from Did, I managed to get some preliminary ideas. I am not completely sure if the following is correct, thus, if you find an error please tell.

My process is an iterated random function:
\begin{align*}
X_{n+1}=f_{\theta_{n+1}}(X_n),\,X_0=2
\end{align*}
with $\theta_k$ iid random variables being either $1$ or $2$ with probability $1/2$, and
\begin{align*}
f_1(x)&=qx+1\\
f_2(x)&=(1-q)x+1.
\end{align*}

The first thing I learned from Diaconis & Freedman (1999) is that the forward iteration
\begin{align*}
X_{n+1}=(f_{\theta_{n+1}}\circ\ldots\circ f_{\theta_{1}})(x_0)
\end{align*}
has the same distribution as the backward iteration
\begin{align*}
Y_{n+1}=(f_{\theta_{1}}\circ\ldots\circ f_{\theta_{n+1}})(x_0).
\end{align*}

This is useful because the forward process is ergodic, while the backward process converges. Specifically,
\begin{align*}
Y_\infty=1+a_1+a_1a_2+\ldots = \sum_{j=0}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^{j}a_i,
\end{align*}
with $a_k$ either $q$ or $1-q$ with probability $1/2$. Denoting the first $N$ terms of $Y_\infty$ as $Z_N$, and letting $Z^q_N$ be the first $N$ terms with $a_{N-1}=q$, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
Z_N^q&=1+\ldots+\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i+q\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i\\
Z_N^{1-q}&=1+\ldots+\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i+(1-q)\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i.
\end{align*}
Then, we define $R_N^q=Z_\infty^q-Z_N^q$. By doing some calculations, we find out that
\begin{align*}
\frac{q^2}{1-q}\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i\leq R_N^q\leq (1-q)\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i\\
q\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i\leq R_N^{1-q}\leq \frac{(1-q)^2}{q}\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}a_i,
\end{align*}
and, thus, $Z_N^q+R_N^q\leq Z_N^{1-q}+R_N^{1-q}$, meaning that an iteration of the backward iteration "splits" the realizations in two groups, such that each group ends up in a given interval, with the overlap between the intervals having measure zero. Furthermore, both groups have the same mass, and it also follows (I don't do all steps here) that the stationary distributions in the interior of both intervals have to be the same (except scaling of axis), and to be the same as the whole distribution (Note: I have to check this again). This again implies, if I didn't make some mistake, that every interval contains the information about the whole distribution. I guess with a few more arguments it follows that the distribution cannot be uniformly continuous, explaining its roughness.

Comment: The transformation $X_{i+1}=A_iX_i+B_i$ with $(A_i,B_i)$ i.i.d., $P(A_i=q)=P(A_i=1-q)=\frac12$ and $P(B_i=1)=1$, is an example of **iterated random functions**. [A survey of the subject](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036144598338446) was written by Persi Diaconis and David Freedman a few years ago.

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot for the reference, which was very helpful. I think with it I am on a good track to figure out the solution to my problem; thus, if you re-post your comment as an answer, I will award the bounty to you. I will also try to post some preliminary answers to the problem, in case others stumble over the question.

Comment: The expectation can be computed easily:  For any $q \in [0,1]$ and any initial condition $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, you have $E[X_{i+1}|X_i]=\frac{1}{2}X_i+1$ and so $E[X_{i+1}]=\frac{1}{2}E[X_i]+1$ for all $i$.  So $$ E[X_i]=2+(E[X_0]-2)(1/2)^i \quad \forall i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$  and $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} E[X_i]=2$.  In the special case when $q=1/2$ the process is deterministic and so is equal to its expectation, that is, $X_i=2+(X_0-2)(1/2)^i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mean

Fix $q \in (0,1)$ and consider any initial condition $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.   From my above comment, the expectation is $E[X_i]  = 2 + (E[X_0]-2)(1/2)^i$ for $i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$. Hence,
$$  \boxed{E[X_0]=2 \implies E[X_i] = 2 \quad \forall i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}} $$

#### Second moment

Fix $q \in (0,1)$ and assume $E[X_0]=2$, so $E[X_i]=2$ for all $i$.  Define $c = \frac{1}{2}(q^2+(1-q)^2)$. We have: 
\begin{align}
E[X_{i+1}^2|X_i] &= \frac{1}{2}(qX_i+1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}((1-q)X_i+1)^2\\
&= 1 + X_i + \frac{1}{2}(q^2+(1-q)^2)X_i^2\\
&= 1 + X_i + cX_i^2
\end{align}
Thus, $E[X_{i+1}^2] = 1 + E[X_i] + cE[X_i^2] = 3 + cE[X_i^2]$ for all $i$. Thus: 
$$ \boxed{E[X_0]=2 \implies E[X_{i}^2] = \frac{3}{1-c} + \left(E[X_0^2]-\frac{3}{1-c}\right)c^i  \quad \forall i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} }$$
If $E[X_0]=2$ and $E[X_0^2]=\frac{3}{1-c}$ then $E[X_i]=2$ and $E[X_i^2]=\frac{3}{1-c}$ for all $i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.

#### Moment generating function and density

$$ E[e^{rX_{i+1}}|X_i] = \frac{1}{2}e^{r(qX_i+1)} + \frac{1}{2}e^{r((1-q)X_i+1)}$$
$$ \implies E[e^{rX_{i+1}}] = \left(\frac{1}{2}e^r\right)\left(E[e^{rqX_i}]+E[e^{r(1-q)X_i}]\right) $$
Define $F(r) = \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}E[e^{rX_i}]$, assuming the limit exists.  Then: 
$$ F(r) = \left(\frac{1}{2}e^r\right)\left[F(rq) + F(r(1-q))  \right] $$
Let $f(x)$ be the "generalized steady state density," which is the inverse transform of $F(r)$.  So we get by basic scaling and modulation properties of transforms: 
$$ \boxed{f(x) = \frac{1}{2q}f\left(\frac{x-1}{q}\right) + \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f\left(\frac{x-1}{1-q}\right) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}} $$
and this same equation could be alternatively derived by defining $f(x)$ as the density that satisfies (for small $\delta >0$): 
$$ f(x)\delta \approx \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}P[X_i \in [x, x+\delta]] $$

#### "Roughness" and self-similarity of the density

The density $f(x)$ is indeed "self-similar" (it is equal to shifted and scaled versions of itself) and "rough" (in that it rises and falls infinitely many times, with infinitely many zeros over the interval in which it is defined).

In particular, assuming that $q>1/2$ and $X_0=2$ with probability 1, it can be shown that $X_i \in [1/q, 1/(1-q)]$ for all $i$, so $f(x)=0$ outside that interval. Now take $x \in [1/q, 2)$.  From the previous boxed equation: 
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{2q}f\left(\frac{x-1}{q} \right)+ \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f\left(\frac{x-1}{1-q}\right) \\
&= 0 + \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f\left(\frac{x-1}{1-q}\right)
\end{align}
where the last equality holds because $\frac{x-1}{q}<\frac{1}{q}$ whenever $x<2$, and $f(y)=0$ when $y<1/q$. Hence, 
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f\left(\frac{x-1}{1-q}\right) \quad \forall x \in [1/q, 2) $$
and so $f$ is equal to a shifted and scaled version of itself over that interval.

Evaluating the above equation at $x=1/q$ gives:
\begin{align}
f(1/q) = \frac{1}{2(1-q)}\underbrace{f\left(\frac{1/q-1}{1-q}\right)}_{f(1/q)}
\end{align}
Hence, $f(1/q) = \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f(1/q)$ and so $f(1/q)=0$. Similarly, it can be shown that: 
 $$f(1/q)=f(1/(1-q))=f(2)=0$$ 
We can also get infinitely many more zeros over the interval $[1/q, 1/(1-q)]$.  This is explained in the next section.

#### Infinite zeros for $f$

Suppose $q \in (1/2, 1)$ and $X_0=2$ with probability 1.  We know from above that $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin [1/q, 1/(1-q)]$.  Also, $f(1/q)=f(1/(1-q))=f(2)=0$.

Claim:  We have $f(x_k)=0$ for points $x_k$ defined by
$$x_k= \frac{1}{q} + \left(2-\frac{1}{q}\right)(1-q)^k \quad, \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$

Proof: We already know it holds for $k=0$ since $f(2)=0$. Suppose it holds for $x_k$.  We show it also holds for $x_{k+1}$. Notice that $\frac{x_{k+1}-1}{1-q}=x_{k}$.  Hence, from the above boxed equation with $x=x_{k+1}$:
\begin{align}
f(x_{k+1}) &= \frac{1}{2q}f\left(\frac{x_{k+1}-1}{q}\right) + \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f\left(\frac{x_{k+1}-1}{1-q}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2q}f(\frac{x_k(1-q)}{q}) + \frac{1}{2(1-q)}f(x_k)\\
&= \frac{1}{2q}f(\frac{x_k(1-q)}{q}) + 0 \quad [\mbox{by induction hypothesis $f(x_k)=0$}]\\
& = 0 
\end{align}
where the final equality holds because $\frac{x_k(1-q)}{q}\leq \frac{1}{q}$ and $f(x)=0$ whenever $x \leq 1/q$. $\Box$

Comment: Similarly, we have $f(y_k)=0$ for points $y_k = \frac{1}{1-q} - (\frac{1}{1-q}-2)q^k$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.  In particular, for $q = \pi/5$ we have zeros at points $y_0=2$, $y_1\approx 2.2566$, $y_2\approx 2.4179$, $y_3 \approx 2.5192$, $y_4 \approx 2.5828$, and so on, which is consistent with the engineertryingmath simulated picture.

Comment: Note that throughout I am using: (i) The _law of iterated expectations_:  $E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]$ for any random vector $(X,Y)$. (ii) A linear difference equation of the form $a_{k+1} = \theta a_k + b$ has a _particular solution_ $a_k=\frac{b}{1-\theta}$ for all $k \geq 0$, and _homogeneous solution_ $a_k = c\theta^k$ for all $k\geq 0$ (for any desired constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$), and so the general solution for initial condition $a_0$ is $$a_k = \underbrace{\frac{b}{1-\theta}}_{particular} + \underbrace{(a_0 - \frac{b}{1-\theta})\theta^k}_{homogeneous} \quad \forall k \geq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

So the distribution is a singular multi-fractal measure. This one looks close in appearance to the singular binomial measure. Here are some introductions to multi-fractals and the measure.

Rice: Intorduction to Multifractals Rudolf H. Reidi-www.stat.rice.edu/~riedi/Publ/PDF/intro.pdf

Rice: Binomial Multifractals-www.stat.rice.edu/~riedi/Publ/TALKS/TalkMfrPr.pdf

[Yale Online Course](http://users.math.yale.edu/public_html/People/frame/Fractals/MultiFractals/WSMultifractals.html)

[Wolfram Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MandelbrotsBinomialMeasureMultifractal/)

So there are references. And it seems another answer has information about moments, so I won't add to that.